# Choosing integers from a set such that no chosen integer can be formed by summing other chosen integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was working on a problem today where I needed to pick six distinct integers between $1$ and $24$ inclusive such that none of the integers that I picked can be achieved by summing any other of the remaining five integers.

So through a bit of trial and error I came up with the set $11,17,20,22,23,24$ which satisfies the requirements, but it took me a long time to figure the possible integers.

Is there any systematic way to pick these integers from the given set?

Comment: Just pick  interval $[19,24]$ and you're done...

Answer (score 2):

Well, if $a, b \geq \frac{n}{2}$ and $a \neq b$, then $a + b > n$. So $\{24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19\}$ works.

Comment: This could become a slightly different problem: what is the set of such integers with the smallest maximum member?  I think it's probably $[5,10]$...